# onclick function error when clicking Button

Tags: javascript, html

I am passing a parameter to an onclick function but it gives me an error when I am trying to console the parameter
my code

```
function createAllPlacesElement(placeName, key){
var html = 
'<div class="col-sm-4"><div class="card">'+
'<p class="placeName"></p>';

var html1= 
'<div class="card"><a class="idkey" onclick="show('+ key +' ) "><button class="placeName">jhsdjkhfj</button></a></div>';

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = html1;
var dataElement = div.firstChild;

dataElement.getElementsByClassName('placeName')[0].innerHTML = placeName;




return dataElement;
}

function show(key) {
 window.alert(key);
}
```

it gives me that error when click the Button :

Uncaught ReferenceError: L6w_E36ki97TsRMxe2z is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (index.html:1)

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript injecting requires some quotes - this is what you have.

```
'<div class="card"><a class="idkey" onclick="show('+ key +' ) "><button class="placeName">jhsdjkhfj</button></a></div>';
```

The key is being inserted without quotes around it - should be `show(\"' + key + '\")` or `show(\'' + key + '\')`.

Comment: gave me that error :Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: Sorry @MuhammadNoamany I wrote bad code. I've just updated it.